# The value of variables in a process after few executions

Tags: variables, process, integer, signals, clock

Let say I have some process in which i have initialized some variable.

```
process (clk) is

variable integer := 0;

begin

if (clk'event and clk='1') and (integer<32) then
   integer := integer +1;
end if;

if (integer = 32) then
   BusyOUT <= '1';  -- This is some outside signal
end if;

end proces;
```

Will this code set integer to 0 each time clk is on rising edge (since it will execute the entire code), or will it initialize integer to 0 only once (on first read rising edge of the clock, since it is in sensitivity list) and than increment it every time the clk is on rising edge until it reaches 32 and than it will activate the control BusyOUT signal (some outer signal) with which it will stop raising integer?

Thanks in advance,
Bojan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in meanwhile I figured that the part between the process and begin is executed only once.